# Install error in lwgeom package R, using custom PROJ location

Tags: r, linux, installation, install.packages, proj

```
cd ${install_directory}
mkdir lwgeom
cd lwgeom
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/lwgeom_0.1-4.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-proj-include=${install_directory}/proj/include --with-proj-lib=${install_directory}/proj/lib" lwgeom_0.1-4.tar.gz
```

ends up with the error:

```
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘lwgeom’
```

DESPITE:

```
ls ${install_directory}/proj/include
geodesic.h  org_proj4_PJ.h  proj_api.h  projects.h  proj.h
```

Any ideas? I don't have sudo access so I have to use this version of proj